# Using animated textures from mpeg file in OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, mpeg

I design a VRML browser for Android and I need to use animated texture that takes every frame from the specified mpeg file and maps it as a simple texture. How can I do that?

Comment: I tried to use static textures from JPEG files, and everything is OK with that. But I have no idea how to capture particular frame from the mpeg video programmatically and convert it to bitmap. The actual question is how can I capture a frame from a movie.

Comment: You can't do it with Android's API for the system decoder. You need a 3rd party decoder that is open sourced and can be ported to Android. FFmpeg is a good fit